# Magento Connect permissions are not correct (tried a number of solutions none work) how do I fix this?

Tags: php, apache, magento, ssh, virtualhost

I believe this is a common issue when you get the warning

> Warning: Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions.

I've tried

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;
```

and

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 755 {} ;
```

but that doesn't seam to help, I believe I used different permissions than `777` but I would like to keep it more secure...

I have a feeling that it might be because of my VirtualHost setup. My Magento is at `/var/www/example.com/public_html` and the VirtualHost part is function because `example.com` takes you to my site.

I am not sure `./mage` handles everything properly and is a bit of a pain but I use SSH so that has been my only solution.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't going to be your Apache setup -- this warning has to do with PHP's ability to write files to the file-system.  That's how Magento Connect does its job -- when you're interacting with the GUI frontend PHP will download `tgz` Connect Packages to your local files system, and then uncompress and untar them into your Magento installation.  PHP needs the ability to create folders.  If you're running apache as an unprivileged user and your folders/files are owned by a privileged user (usually your user account), this means you **need** to give folders `777` if you want to use the Magento Connect GUI to install packages.

What `777` means is any user account on the computer has the right to create files in that directory.  The security risk is if a hacker managed to gain access to an unprivileged user account they'll be able to create files in this folder that will help them exploit the server further, or exploit the web application itself.  If you're on a server that has multiple user accounts (shared hosting) it also means those other users have the right to create files in those folders.

Good shared hosting companies have monitoring to help prevent this, but most shared hosting companies are not good, and this permissions problem is probably the most common reason for exploits to **any** PHP based web application.

Also, the Magento Connect GUI is notorious for passing on false information about permissions.  You'll often run into situations where it reports something installed successfully, but hasn't.  If you run into this situation I wrote an `n98-magerun` command a while back that can [validate a connect extension](http://alanstorm.com/magento_connect_validate_extension) as correctly installed or not.

So, to your specific problem, the best way to track this down is to look at Magento Connect's source and determine which file(s)/folder(s) it thinks have incorrect permissions.

```
$ ack 'Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions' downloader

downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Install.php
105:                    'Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions, which downloader requires.'

downloader/template/install/writable.phtml
32:<p>Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions, which this web based downloader requires.</p>

downloader/template/writable.phtml
28:    <h4>Warning: Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions.</h4>
```

The first place is an exception message

```
#File: downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Install.php
if (!$isWritable) {
    $this->doError($command, $err);
    throw new Exception(
        'Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions, which downloader requires.'
    );
}
```

If you look in the try block, you'll see two places where `isWritable` could be set to false

```
    $isWritable = is_writable($config->magento_root)
                  && is_writable($config->magento_root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $config->downloader_path)
                  && is_writable($config->magento_root . $dirCache)
                  && is_writable($config->magento_root . $dirTmp)
                  && is_writable($config->magento_root . $dirMedia);

$isWritable = $isWritable && is_writable($config->magento_root . $dirMedia)
              && is_writable($config->magento_root . $dirCache)
              && is_writable($config->magento_root . $dirTmp);
```

Adding some temporary debugging code after these lines can help you track down which directories Magento thinks don't have write permissions.

```
if(!$isWritable)
{
    var_dump($config->magento_root);
    var_dump(is_writable($config->magento_root));

    var_dump($config->magento_root . $dirCache);
    var_dump(is_writable($config->magento_root . $dirCache));
    //etc..
}
```

Next up are those `writable.phtml` template files.  Magento connect has its own simple template system, so we'll want to search for places where it renders these `writable.phtml templates`

```
$ ack 'writable.phtml' downloader
downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
28:<?php if ($this->get('writable_warning')) echo $this->template('writable.phtml');?>
```

It's only mention is in **another** template. If we search for this `packages.phtml` template file

```
$ ack 'packages.phtml' downloader
downloader/Maged/Controller.php
315:        echo $this->view()->template('connect/packages.phtml');
```

We'll find the `writable_warning` variable is set is the `isWritable` method

```
File: downloader/Maged/Controller.php
if (!$this->isWritable() && empty($remoteConfig)) {
    $this->view()->set('writable_warning', true);
}    

public function isWritable()
{
    if (is_null($this->_writable)) {
        $this->_writable = is_writable($this->getMageDir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)
            && is_writable($this->filepath())
            && (!file_exists($this->filepath('config.ini') || is_writable($this->filepath('config.ini'))));
    }
    return $this->_writable;
}
```

Again, some temporary debugging code  can help us figure out why Magento thinks it doesn't have correct permissions.

```
    if (is_null($this->_writable)) {
        var_dump(is_writable($this->getMageDir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
        var_dump(is_writable($this->filepath()));
        var_dump((!file_exists($this->filepath('config.ini') || is_writable($this->filepath('config.ini'));
        //etc...
        $this->_writable = is_writable($this->getMageDir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)
            && is_writable($this->filepath())
            && (!file_exists($this->filepath('config.ini') || is_writable($this->filepath('config.ini'))));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer should actually be: do not use Magento Connect. Use a proper version control system like git, separate core files from customisations via modman or composer. This is the correct and technically clean approach and prevents using Magento Connect.